# Set variable based on currently active test case

Tags: automation, robotframework

I have the following situation. Test.robot is my robot suite with 4 test cases.

```
***Settings**

Resource  Python Resource files


Suite Setup  ${xyz}
Suite Teardown  ${xyz} 

Test Setup  ${Xyz}

***Variables***

/*This is pointing to the folder with my data files*/
${data}  {CURDIR}/


*** Test Cases ***

Test_case1
Test_case2
Test_case3 
Test_case4
```

I have a directory with folders
1. Test_Case1
2. Test_Case2
3. Test_Case3
4. Test_Case4
test.robot (my robot suite)

The above 4 folders have the data files that my tests(test_case1, test_case2, test_case3,test_case4) will access while running. I am not sure how to set the variable such that it dynamically access the specific test folder when the test.robot suite is run.

I mean, when I run test.robot all four tests(test_case1, test_case2 etc) will run. I am unsure how to set the Variable ${data} such that it dynamically accesses the correct test_case folder when the specific test case is running

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [automatic variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) `${TEST NAME}` to retrieve the currently active test case's name and set your own variable using the data you extracted from this variable.